# Is there a way to record scrollbar movement?

Tags: tracking, visitors

Simply put, I would like to know if customers are looking at the whole page or not, to decide whether I should rearrange the content, moving it up on that page or not.

Is there a way to record the scrollbar movement on a certain page, or visually record visitor's behavior for that matter? Perhaps even a whole other way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Crazy Egg](http://www.crazyegg.com/) has a featured called scrollmap that can do this

Comment: I love how learning new things is only a click away. Thank you very much sir, that is exactly what I was looking for and it is also very affordable.